# Plugins error (Use roles and capabilities instead) on latest version, multisite

Tags: plugins, errors

I have the latest, version 3.1.2 and have multisite installed. I have debug on true for testing purposes. I get the follow error when I install plugins.

Where and how do I fix this?

> Error:
>   Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3387

thanks in advance!

Comment: A Plugin is using a deprecated function and/or function argument. You should file a bug report with the Plugin developer. WPSE shouldn't be used for reporting bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You are fine , its the plugins who are bad!
some plugins have not been updated and are still using User level as capability when adding menu pages instead of capability, for example

```
 10 = manage_options = admin
```

take a look at [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/has_cap-was-called-with-an-argument-that-is-deprecated) to understand better.

Comment: yes, that's right I just disable one by one of my installed plugin. so I can seek and find that plugin (that use the wrong level as the capability). when the log is enabled there is 4 error on top of the wp-admin page. I search and find your reply then disable and found the deprecated plugin and revert back all those good plugins. everything ok now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who meets this issue, you can fix it by changing the parameter of `add_options_page` like this:

> ```
>        add_options_page(__('WP Flickr Embed', 'wp-flickr-embed'), __('WP Flickr Embed', 'wp-flickr-embed'), 8, $this->pagesDir.'/admin.php');
>        add_options_page(__('WP Flickr Embed', 'wp-flickr-embed'), __('WP Flickr Embed', 'wp-flickr-embed'), 'manage_options', $this->pagesDir.'/admin.php');
> ```

Change the number parameter to `'manage_options'` if its `8`. For other number, you need to do a search.

> https://github.com/travisseitler/wp-flickr-embed/commit/d3b03191061e46f4850dce407bb55cf5161c5380

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two places to check for this error -- one is when adding a menu / page as in 'add_options_page', and the other is when explicitly checking the capability with current_user_can and its like.

Also, a plugin should not use roles -- it should use capabilities.  So for the function I just mentioned 'add_options_page', the capability is probably 'manage_options'.

Roles are for the user to have, which are a grouping of capabilities.